# Bash Select Menu Formatting without Tabs

Tags: bash

I've built a simple select menu in Bash. It's currently displaying the menu horizontally (with tabs) like so:

```
1) Create a VM from scratch   3) Command-line Usage
2) Management Menu            4) Quit
```

I'd like the list to look like this:

```
1) Create a VM from scratch  
2) Management Menu
3) Command-line Usage     
4) Quit
```

**UPDATE**: Here's my code:

```
PS3="Please choose a valid option : "
OPTIONS=("Create a VM from scratch" "Management Menu" "Command-line Usage" "Quit")
select opt in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do
    case $opt in
            "Create a VM from scratch")
                 createit
                 exit
                 ;;
            "Management Menu")
                 mgmtmenu
                 exit
                 ;;
            "Command-line Usage ")
                 help
                 ;;
            "Quit")
                exit
                ;;
            *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

**How can I display the select menu with each option on it's own line?**

Comment: Could you post the code used to create your current menu? Also, [this link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-9.html) seems to answer your requisites.

Comment: @Aaron : The link your provided doesn't answer op's requirement. I tested with 8 it didn't.

Comment: Well there might be some environment variables that affect the way `select` displays its menu.

Comment: I think so @Aaron but couldn't figure out which one affects the behavior. Documentation is sparse ;)

Comment: I've tried it on a few different systems (OSX, Centos, Ubuntu) and all are showing like my output above.

Comment: looks like there's a `$COLUMNS` environment variable that modifies this behaviour. I'm testing it and will post an answer in a few minutes if successful.

Comment: Yep, just set $COLUMNS to 1 and it's forcing down to 1 column...but only for a second, something is causing it to revert back

Comment: Oh well I'm glad it works for you, I couldn't get it to work on my environment (but I'm using cygwin, so that might explain why)

Comment: Been using Bash for years, but today I learned about `select` loops!

Comment: NVM...I just added the export to the script itself and it forces it everytime. Thanks @Aaron

Comment: `(COLUMNS=1; select opt in ...)` seems to work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash defines a `$COLUMNS` environment variable that is read by `select`.

As seen in bash's `man` :

> ```
> COLUMNS
>          Used by the select compound command to  determine  the  terminal
>          width  when  printing selection lists.  Automatically set if the
>          checkwinsize option is enabled or in an interactive  shell  upon
>          receipt of a SIGWINCH.
> ```

Comment: Great job, great answer :-) Interestingly `COLUMNS` is not defined by default in my shell. Just added to the script and it works like a charm. :-)